# Git question: What's the best way to merge my release branch back into develop?

Tags: git

I have a release branch named `release/1.29.1`. It has different files with version information, like gradle.properties, which contains, **version=release-1.29.1-rc1**. Then I have the `develop` branch, whose gradle.properties contains **version=1.29.0-SNAPSHOT** (it hasn't been moved to 1.30 yet, btw).

There are a few commits in `release/1.29.1` that I need to git into `develop`. So I checked out `develop` and tried cherry-picking the first commit from `release/1.29.1`, but git says the commit is unknown. So I did the following:

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin release/1.29.1
```

But the gradle.properties file in `develop` changes to `version=1.29.1-rc1`, when I want to it stay at `1.29.0-SNAPSHOT`. I have 20 different `release/1.29.1` repositories, with 20 different `develop` repos, and I don't want to have to go through all of them to reset the versions.

Is there any way around this? Or am not thinking about this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version change was in a separate commit (which it should have been), you can pull release into develop via rebasing (`git pull --rebase=interactive`) and drop the version change commit.

Some developers dislike rebasing, but I think it is applicable and even a good practice, for example in cases like this.

Cherry-picking the commits you want should also have worked (assuming release originally branched off of develop) - you should respond with the exact error you get and maybe we can figure out why it didn't.

Comment: Thanks! I ran that, and I get an error: `git pull release/1.29.1 --rebase=interactive
fatal: 'release/1.29.1' does not appear to be a git repository`. That is the name of the branch though...

Comment: try `origin release/1.29.1` instead

Comment: That almost worked! So I picked the two commits I wanted, but now git says "The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution. If you wish to commit it anyway, use: git commit --allow-empty". I don't understand why the cherry-pick is empty?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. That particular commit has already been merged. Question answered! Thanks!